# Bash $? Variable Assignement

Tags: bash, exitstatus

I just started learning bash and I was reading about [the `$?` variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html). From what I understood, `$?` is assigned to the exit status of the last command executed.

For example

```
$ false; echo $?
```

Will yield 1, and

```
$ false; :; echo $?
```

Will yield 0

Things get a bit more complicated when I combine these with if/for blocks. The man page reads:

> ### `for` *NAME* [`in` *WORDS* ... ] `;` `do` *COMMANDS*`;` `done`
>
> Execute commands for each member in a list.
>
> The `for` loop executes a sequence of commands for each member in a
>       list of items.  If `in WORDS ...;` is not present, then `in "$@"` is
>       assumed.  For each element in *WORDS*, *NAME* is set to that element, and
>       the *COMMANDS* are executed.
>
> #### Exit Status:
>
> Returns the status of the last command executed.

That means:

```
$ false; for i in 1 2 3; do false; done; echo $?
```

Will yield 1 since the last command executed is false. But

```
$ false; for i in; do false; done; echo $?
```

or

```
$ false; if false; then :; fi; echo $?
```

Will yield 0 despite the fact that false was the last command executed.

My guess is the `$?` variable is set to 0 when entering a for/if block. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [bash's manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html):

> `if` *list* ; `then` *list* ; [ `elif` *list* ; `then` *list* ; ] ... [ `else` *list* ; ] `fi`
>
> > The `if`*`list`* is executed.  If its exit status is zero, the `then`*`list`*  is  executed.   Otherwise,  each `elif`*`list`* is executed in
> >      turn, and if its exit status is zero,  the  corresponding `then`*`list`*  is  executed  and  the command completes.  Otherwise, the `else`*`list`* is executed, if present.  **The exit status** <sup>(of the whole `if ... fi` block)</sup> **is the exit status  of  the  last command** <sup>(in the `then`, `elif` or `else` block)</sup> **executed, or zero if no condition tested true.**

Comment: Great! Thats makes a lot of sense. Could you provide a link to the refered paragraph?

Comment: Did not find the man page from [GNU's site](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/). Linked to Chet's page. Just update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

yes, after `if ..;`, `for ..;` or `while ..;` statements the exit status reset to 0.

to be clear this doesn't mean after `fi;` or `done;` because the exit status is the last command exit status.

EDIT : commands between `if`/`elif` and `then` doesn't affect exit status of compound statement whereas latest command executed between `then`/`else` and `elif`/`fi` sets the exit status of compound statement.

after a function call; the exit status will be the value returned by `return` or the exit status of last command.

with the option `set -e`, `set -o errexit`; the shell exits after a command with a <>0 exit status, except if followed by `||` or inside a `if ..;` statement.

exit status must be checked just after command exits, logical operators can be used `&&`, `||`:

```
# to fail fast the process can't continue
simple_command || {
    echo "failed .."
    exit 1
}
```

the error handling is similar to exceptions, the question to be asked is does or how the process can continue after a command fails?

in pipeline commands the exit status is the exit status of the last command except with `set -o pipefail` : the exit status will be the exit status of the latest command in the pipe with exit status <>0.

Comment: To be clear, compound statements do not reset the exit status. The exit status is *defined* to be 0 if no command executes as a result of the compound statement.

Comment: @chepner, thanks for clarifying, commands failing inside `if list;` `while list;` `until list;` do not affect the exit status

Comment: after `else` keyword `echo $?;` gives the exit status of last `if` `elif` command:  `if (exit 2); then :; elif (exit 3); then :; else echo $?; fi;` but when there is no `else` statement status is 0: `if (exit 2); then :; elif (exit 3); then :; fi;echo $?`

Comment: Yes, because none of the tested conditions returned true. I think the thing to emphasize is that a compound statement *itself* (and not the commands executed *inside* it) does not affect the value of `$?`, except under very specific corner cases,

Answer (score 1):

Command `$ false; for i in; do false; done; echo $?` gives the exit status of `for loop`. Since it exits for-loop without errors, `$?` is 0.
Here is a similar question which may be helpful.
[How to get the exit status a loop in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059342/how-to-get-the-exit-status-a-loop-in-bash)

Comment: More precisely, the exit status of a loop is the exit status of the last command executed in the body, unless the loop never executes its body (as in this case, where `for i in; do` has an empty list to iterate over), in which case the exit status is defined to be 0.