# Bash script to check if a directory is created

Tags: bash

What is the best way to monitor a directory on webserver and automatically create following directories if something happens.

e.g

A **dir_1** gets created in **monitored_dir**.
Auto creation of dir_1-1, dir_1-2, ... in **dir_1**.

Comment: What would create `dir_1` ?

Comment: You can probably come up with something from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542430/inotify-and-bash

Comment: @gogaz manual creation

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you want to do, but think like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMBER=0
DIR=/srv/monitored_dir/dir_1/

if [[ ! -d "${DIR}" ]]; then
  while [[ $NUMBER -lt 4 ]]; do
    mkdir "${DIR}"-dir_1-"${NUMBER}"
    NUMBER=$["${NUMBER}"+1]
  done
fi
```